# Endowed Assistant Professor vs Assistant Professor

Tags: professorship, job, academic-life, assistant-professor

In US education system, the university academic positions start with Assistant Professor. But there are some occasions that positions for Endowed Assistant Professor are advertised. I could not find what exactly is *"endowed Associated Prof"*. Is there any difference with assistant professor? Is it a type of position different from tenure track or the title endowed comes from the particular funding source? There is a similar discussion about endowed chair in US system [here](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/12607/what-is-an-endowed-chair-exactly-how-does-it-compare-to-a-normal-position/12608#12608), but I think that is slightly different.

Please let me know, whas recruitment committee members are concerned about when hiring endowed assistant professor.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There really is very little difference between the [answer Chris Gregg posted](https://academia.stackexchange.com/a/12608/53) and the answer for this question. An "endowed" assistant professorship is a position which provides funds for the group of the faculty member appointed to the professorship. It can be either salary, or perhaps additional funds that can be used to support members of the group.

Usually, applicants are not hired directly into such positions; instead, they are hired to the department first, and then appointed into such positions after a few years. They often have names like "career development assistant professorship" which indicate that this is a transient award, not a permanent one. If the hiring advertisement actually specifies the position as an "endowed" assistant professorship, I don't think it really changes the hiring process, except that they're looking for the best candidate who satisfies the conditions of the endowment.

Comment: _Usually, applicants are not hired directly into such positions_, I guess this is an unusual case. I have seen it in a recent ad in a US-based computer department that plans to employ directly from outside the university for this position.

Answer (score 3):

In mathematics, at least, some departments have multiple positions called "So-and-so Assistant Professor" (e.g. Szegö Assistant Professors at Stanford ), which are non-tenure track, 2–3 year visiting positions — basically, a postdoc who teaches (with teaching duties similar to, or somewhat lighter than, the senior faculty).  I don't know whether this practice exists in other fields.  For such positions, the hiring considerations are similar to other postdoc positions.

Comment: As far as I know, these named assistant professorships are usually not endowed.  They're funded by the university just like other faculty positions.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, there ARE actual endowed tenure-track assistant professorships. Several of these are found at prominent liberal-arts colleges. And as with an endowed professorship at full professor rank, these too are funded by the endowment.