# In what parts of the world, besides the US, do endowed chairs exist?

Tags: career-path, professorship

[Browsing academia.SE](https://academia.stackexchange.com/q/100956/9646), I discovered the existence of "endowed chairs" or "named chairs", i.e. professorships named in the honor of someone else and paid for by a donor with a gift to the university. I've never heard of anything like that before (I live and work in France so I mostly meet European academics).

Apart from the US (where this apparently exist), do endowed chairs exist elsewhere in the world?

Comment: Not all named chairs are endowed, although nowadays the fundraisers would not be happy to see a "naming opportunity" squandered.

Answer (score 11):

Yes, endowed chairs exist outside the USA.

An example is the [Lucasian Professor of Mathematics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lucasian_Professor_of_Mathematics) at the University of Cambridge, which (according to Wikipedia) was founded in 1663 by Henry Lucas, the then Member of Parliament for Cambridge. The post has been held by the likes of Isaac Newton, Paul Dirac and Stephen Hawking.

Comment: Thanks. So perhaps it's more common in the Anglo-Saxon world.

Comment: @NajibIdrissi I have seen similar things in Scandinavia but I can't find a concrete example.

Comment: @NajibIdrissi [Germany](https://www.wiwi.uni-frankfurt.de/en/faculty/faculty-a-z/endowed-chairs.html) has them (UBS Endowed Chair of Strategic Management)

Comment: They exist in Australia too, e.g. https://www.garvan.org.au/news-events/news/garvan-breast-cancer-researcher-awarded-10-year-endowed-chair

Answer (score 2):

In Nigeria , Endowed chairs exist; an example is the University of Lagos which has the Enoch Adeboye professorial chair for Mathematics, Named after the University's top donor, Pastor Enoch Adeboye.