# Is it okay to mention what a different chair is working on?

Tags: thesis, masters, advisor, confidentiality

I'm a university student and am looking for a master's thesis topic. I also have a job at a company and this company is cooperating with a chair / staff of a chair (i.e. people working for a teaching professor) from a different faculty but the same university to help them with a paper. The paper now is almost ready to be published and I have an idea for a master's thesis where that paper could help. When I'm discussing my idea with my advisor, is it okay to mention that I know that a paper about that topic is coming out soon and that I already read it several times while looking over it?

Comment: *is cooperating with a chair from a different faculty* --- Could you clarify what "chair" means in your context? [This](https://tophat.com/glossary/d/department-chair/) or [this](https://academia.stackexchange.com/q/121911/49593) or [this](https://academia.stackexchange.com/q/12607/49593) etc. (presumably not [this](https://www.ikea.com/us/en/images/products/stefan-chair__0727320_PE735593_S5.JPG)).

Comment: @DaveLRenfro I added a clarifying remark.

Comment: "Chair", for the meanings I know of, refers to a single object or a single person, but you appear to identify "chair" with a group of people (e.g. "people working for a professor"). Thus, it is still not clear to me what your meaning of "chair" is --- is it another word for a professor (perhaps a professor having some kind of special designation) or it is another word for the group of people (presumably also including the professor) who work under the supervision of a professor? I think you just mean a professor (i.e. a single non-student, non-staff member of the university).

Comment: *is cooperating with a chair (i.e. people working for a professor) from a different faculty but the same university* --- My guess for a rewrite: "is cooperating with a supervisor from a different faculty group but at the same university".

Comment: @DaveLRenfro This seems to be a language problem. I'm German and in Germany, the word "Lehrstuhl" ("lehr" = teaching; "stuhl" = chair) technically describes a professor that teaches at a university. However, it is more commonly used to refer to all of the professor's scientific staff (so not the secretary), all of the lectures, and all of the things that professor's scientific staff do professionally. The professor is then viewed more like the "owner" of a Lehrstuhl. No professor is personally working on that paper (only his staff) and most thesis advisors are not professors but staff.

Comment: Thanks, I learned something new to me. I know that "professor", "faculty member", etc. can have different meanings than in the U.S., but I assumed "chair" still referred to a single person; I just didn't know what type of person (which I thought might marginally be useful to know, but I wasn't sure; maybe it is not important to know for the question). But then the edit to the question seemed to identify "chair" with a group of people. So I guess here "chair" means something vaguely like "department" (perhaps more like "research group"), but a bit more localized.

Comment: By "reviewing it" do you mean "reviewing it for publication" in an academic journal? Or just advising as a subject matter expect by way of the company you work for?

Comment: @TylerH I reviewed it and they used that term but it was not like a review for publication in a journal. I will change that term because it is clearly confusing. I found security problems with the proposals they made, for example.